# Abscissa of Absolute Convergence and Abscissa of Convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

It is well-known if $\sigma_a$ is abscissa of absolute convergence of $f(s)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n^{s}}$, then
\begin{align*}
\sigma_c \leq \sigma_a \leq \sigma_c+1
\end{align*}
with $\sigma_c$ is abscissa of convergence of $f$.

I wonder given $\alpha \in (0,1)$, how can we construct a Dirichlet series with $\sigma_a=\sigma_c+\alpha$? For $\sigma_a=\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_a=\sigma_c+1$ we can construct them easily but I haven't found any example for $\sigma_a=\sigma_c+\alpha$. Thank you.

Comment: Pick $0<a<1$ and split the interval from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}$ into pieces of length $[2^{na}]$ (there will be a reminder but is negligible as $n \to \infty$); make a piece all $1$, the following all $-1$ etc (technically at the end when you have the reminder, you continue into the next interval and make the piece now of the next length if you are at $1$ or previous if you are at $-1$; $\sum a_mm^{-s}$ with $a_m$ as above $\pm 1$ depending where $m$ fits, the absolute abscissa is $1$ but the conditional one is $a$ as the partial sums $s_m$ diverge and $\limsup \log |s_m|/\log m=a$ by construction

Comment: @Conrad I am confused when we have reminder, can you elaborate more about what should I put when the piece has reminder?

Comment: The remainder is small in general (the length of each piece over the length of the interval  goes to zero) so just complete it to the next full period of $1$ (so we go with the partial sums to $[2^{(n+1)a}]$ or complete it with$-1$ to get back to zero and start again (or you can always just stop there and add enough $-1$ to get to zero and start again as in either case the lim sup that determines the abscissa is not affected)

Comment: @Conrad thank you, will you put your comment as answer?